# Calculate Hamming Distance with four taxa

Tags: binary, bioinformatics, hamming-distance

I need to compute the Hamming Distance for the set of four taxa, L1, L2, L3, AND L4.

```
L1 = (0,1,0,1,0)
L2 = (0,0,0,0,0)
L3 = (1,0,0,0,0)
L4 = (1,0,1,0,1)
```

How can I do this to compute the hamming distance of all four together?

Comment: [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) is usually defined for two strings.

Comment: This is set as a distance matrix. How would I compute the distance for that?

Comment: Just calculate the distance for each possible pair: [Distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix).

Comment: So if I calculate for each pair: L1 and L2 have a score of 3, L1 and L3 have a score of 2, L1 and L4 have a score of 0, L2 and L3 have a score of 4, L3 and L4 have a score of 3, and L2 and L4 have a score of 2. What will the distance matrix look like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate the distance for each pair:

```
   L1  L2  L3  L4
L1  0   3   2   0
L2  3   0   4   2
L3  2   4   0   3
L4  0   2   3   0
```

How to represent the matrix depends on the programming language you use. Some kind of two-dimensional array (or at least array-of-arrays) should be supported anywhere.